# Will Google remove content such as images with canonical headers to other non-indexed content?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, images, canonical-url, headers

I've set a canonical (`.htaccess`) header from an image to another one.

For instance:

```
site.com/image-small.jpg
```

has a canonical header to:

```
site.com/image.jpg (Original image).
```

However the website only uses the `image-small.jpg` and because of that, `image.jpg` was never read by Google and is not indexed (only `image-small.jpg` is). After about a week, the image was removed from the results.

Is it normal for Google to remove credit from content because the original content is poorly indexed?

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't use rel=canonical headers for images, so you're probably just seeing normal fluctuations (there's no guarantee of indexing).